# How to loop through a dictionary to get all class-properties?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm trying to make a loop through a dictionary (the code in the button_click is the one I'm trying to fix) to get all my class properties. Instead of writing them out one by one like my code look looks now. The current version works fine, but if a should have like 50 properties or more, I think there must be a more easy way to do this with some kind of loop.

```
    class Person
        {
            public int PersNr { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string BioPappa { get; set; }
            public Adress Adress { get; set; }


            public static Dictionary<int, Person> Metod()
            {
                var dict = new Dictionary<int, Person>();

                dict.Add(8706, new Person
                {
                    Name = "Person",
                    PersNr = 8706,
                    BioPappa = "Dad",
                    Adress = new Adress
                    {
                        Land = "Land",
                        PostNr = 35343,
                        Stad = "city"
                    }
                });

                dict.Add(840, new Person
                {
                    Name = "Person",
                    PersNr = 840,
                    BioPappa = "Erik"
                });
                return dict;

            }

        }

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dictionary<int, Person> myDic = Person.Metod();
            var person = myDic[int.Parse(textBoxSok.Text)];

            listBox1.Items.Add(person.Name);
            listBox1.Items.Add(person.PersNr);
            listBox1.Items.Add(person.BioPappa);
            listBox1.Items.Add(person.Adress.Stad);
            listBox1.Items.Add(person.Adress.PostNr);
            listBox1.Items.Add(person.Adress.Land);           
        }
    }
```

Comment: Populating your dictionary from a file with a loop would be easier. You still need all that data defined somewhere though.

Comment: to me your question is unclear

Comment: keep that way,that is the easier.and if you have 50 properties in one class fix your design.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to make a foreach loop or something for all my listbox1.items.add instead of typing them out one by one like this: listBox1.Items.Add(person.Name);
            listBox1.Items.Add(person.PersNr);
            listBox1.Items.Add(person.BioPappa);
            listBox1.Items.Add(person.Adress.Stad);
            listBox1.Items.Add(person.Adress.PostNr);
            listBox1.Items.Add(person.Adress.Land);

Comment: Sounds like you want to render your person object into some (visual) representation without specifiying how this should be done? Don't know what your output should be, but if it e.g. is a table, can't you assign the whole object as an item to the control and let the control decide which property to show in which column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something to get you started (using `System.Reflection`):

```
private void getProperties(Object obj, ListBox listBox1)
{
    PropertyInfo[] pi = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo p in pi)
    {
        if (p.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
        {
            object o = p.GetValue(obj, null);
            if (o != null)
            {
                if (o is Address)
                    getProperties(o, listBox1);
                else
                    listBox1.Items.Add(o.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this code create an array in which it stores the types/properties 
from the class Person? When i step through the loop all it returns is null. Also, am I supposed to use "using System.Reflection"? 
If dont, I get errors.

Comment: If I change the "if (p.PropertyType.IsGenericType)" to "if (p.PropertyType.IsVisible)". I got it working with the base class witch is "Person". :) But it still doesn't shows the properties to for my Adress class. Do you know why?

Comment: Changed to include Address.

Comment: Yes! It's working! Thank you so mutch for the help. :)